# How I check if my args contains number in Node.js Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, numbers

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

var connection = require('../index.js');

exports.run = (bot, message, args) => {

    var id = args[0];

    var nome = args[1];

    var sobrenome = args[2];

    let verificarId = (id) => {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                connection.query(
                    ' SELECT * FROM `vrp_users` WHERE `id` = ?  ', id,
                    function(err, rows) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err)
                        }
                        if (rows.length > 0) {
                           resolve(true)
                        } else {
                            resolve(false)
                        }
                    }
                );
            } catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    };

    let addId = (id) => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            // check email is exist or not
            let isIdExist = await verificarId(id);
            if (isIdExist) {
                const embed04 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#A0EE45')
                .setAuthor('Tuga Academy - Whitelist', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/793200558248165396/885579421933776956/logosemfundo96.png')
                .setDescription('Mencione um **ID** que não esteja usado.')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(`${message.author.username}`, 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/793200558248165396/885579421933776956/logosemfundo96.png');
                message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
                  message.author.send(embed04);
            } else {
                    if(nome && sobrenome) {
                            message.member.setNickname(""+id+" | "+nome+" "+sobrenome+"");
                            connection.connect(function(err) {
                                var sql = "INSERT INTO `vrp_users`(`id`, `whitelisted`, `banned`) VALUES ('"+id+"','1','0')";
                                connection.query(sql,[id], function (err, result) {
                                    const embed01 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                    .setColor('#A0EE45')
                                    .setAuthor('Tuga Academy - Whitelist', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/793200558248165396/885579421933776956/logosemfundo96.png')
                                    .setDescription('ID **autorizado**.')
                                    .setTimestamp()
                                    .setFooter(`${message.author.username}`, 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/793200558248165396/885579421933776956/logosemfundo96.png');
                                    message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
                                   console.log("ID Autorizado: " + id);
                                    message.author.send(embed01);
                                });
                              });
                    } else {
                        const embed04 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setColor('#A0EE45')
                        .setAuthor('Tuga Academy - Whitelist', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/793200558248165396/885579421933776956/logosemfundo96.png')
                        .setDescription('Mencione um **NOME** e **SOBRENOME**.')
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setFooter(`${message.author.username}`, 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/793200558248165396/885579421933776956/logosemfundo96.png');
                        message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
                          message.author.send(embed04);
                    }
            }
        });
    };

    var pattern = /^([^0-9]*)$/;
    if(id && id.value.match(pattern)) {
        if(nome && nome.value.match(pattern)) {
            if(sobrenome && sobrenome.value.match(pattern)){
                addId(id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is: When someone types -wl "id" "name" "sobrenome" all the data goes to my MYSQL database. This is possible with the function `addId(id)`, but I don’t want numbers in their names. Only letters. I only want to call the function `addId(id)` when `args[1]` (nome) and `args[2]` (sobrenome) don't have numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To check if their entire name has a digit, use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). This will [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) the entire argument (if that is what you check) for a number. This returns true if the number is found, and false if it isn’t.

```js
const numRegex = /\d+/g
console.log(numRegex.test('This has no number'))
console.log(numRegex.test('This has 1 number'))
```

To use this in your code, you will need to use the following

```js
numRegex.test(args[1])
numRegex.test(args[2])
```

Comment: Soo I tested it, but it returns false if the args only have letters, but if it have letters and numbers it returns true, code: https://pastebin.com/NavHhMMa

Comment: Isn’t that what you want?

Comment: What I want is: When someone types -wl "number" "name" "surname" , if the name or surname contains a number ou more returns false and don't let call the function addID(id)

Answer (score 0):

Soo I found another way to fix the issue, I used a regex to filter na username, if it contains numbers, they will be deleted and the nickname will only have letters.

```js
var numberPattern = /[a-zA-Z]+/;
var nome1 = args[1];
var nome2 = args[2];
var nome1f = nome1.match( numberPattern )
var nome2f = nome2.match( numberPattern )
```

Comment: Thank you soo much MrMythical for you help.